# Merge Two Object Data

Tags: c#, object, merge

I have a Class:

```
class MyClass {
  public string Text1 { get; set; }
  public string Text2 { get; set; }
  public string Text3 { get; set; }
}
```

And two objects:

```
var obj1 = new MyClass {Text1 = "Test1", Text2 = "Test2", Text3 = "Test3"};
var obj2 = new MyClass {Text3 = "Another Test"};
```

I want to merge (override obj1 data) these objects so the result would be:

```
mergedObj => {Text1 = "Test1", Text2 = "Test2", Text3 = "Another Test"};
```

I have lots of classes. So I want a method for all of them that gets two objects of a class and return the result. How can I achive this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work, but it doesn't cover all cases (only public properties get copied, no indexed properties):

```
    class MyClass
    {
        public string Text1 { get; set; }
        public string Text2 { get; set; }
        public string Text3 { get; set; }
        public int Int1 { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        var obj1 = new MyClass {Text1 = "Test1", Text2 = "Test2", Text3 = "Test3", Int1 = 0};
        var obj2 = new MyClass {Text3 = "Another Test", Int1 = 1};

        var obj3 = MergeObjects(obj1, obj2);
    }

    public static T MergeObjects<T>(T obj1, T obj2)
    {
        var objResult = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

        var allProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(x => x.CanRead && x.CanWrite);
        foreach (var pi in allProperties)
        {
            object defaultValue;
            if (pi.PropertyType.IsValueType)
            {
                defaultValue = Activator.CreateInstance(pi.PropertyType);
            }
            else
            {
                defaultValue = null;
            }

            var value = pi.GetValue(obj2, null);

            if (value != defaultValue)
            {
                pi.SetValue(objResult, value, null);
            }
            else
            {
                value = pi.GetValue(obj1, null);

                if (value != defaultValue)
                {
                    pi.SetValue(objResult, value, null);
                }
            }
        }

        return (T)objResult;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using Windows Phone 8.1 SDK. I get the error " Cannot resolve symbol 'GetProperties' ". Is that related to WP SDK?

Comment: try adding `using System.Reflection` and using `typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperties()` instead of `typeof(T).GetProperties()`

Comment: Thanks and what about "IsValueType"...?

Comment: Using " pi.GetType().GetTypeInfo().IsValueType ", and it works now. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Aha, great! I don't have a way testing phone apps, so i couldn't just try it myself.